# How to retrieve SQL Server Check Constraint Dependency Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

If I create the following table

```
create table test(
        id1 int,
        id2 int,
        id3 int constraint CK1 check (id3 > 2),
        constraint CK2 check (id1 > id2),
)
```

I can find the dependencies of CK1 by querying `select * from sys.check_constraints`.  The parent_column_id will return the correct answer of 3.  The However, CK2 is a different story, the parent column id returns 0.  Is there another view that can tell me the dependency columns of CK2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can use **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** schema.

```
select cu.*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS c on c.CONSTRAINT_NAME=cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where c.CONSTRAINT_NAME='CK2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use base views

```
select * 
from sys.check_constraints cc
join sys.objects o
  on o.object_id=cc.parent_object_id
```